# How to access the next key in a Swift 3 dictionary?

Tags: swift3

I want to do the same as this code in Swift 3 but it gives me error

```
let arr = Array(myDictionary)
for (ix, (k,v)) in arr.enumerated() {
   println("This key is \(k)")
   if ix < arr.count-1 {
       println("The next key is \(arr[ix+1].0)")
   }
}
```

I wrote this

```
for (i ,item) in arr.enumerated() {
    print(i)
}
```

where item has key and value and I want to access the key and the value in separate variables

Comment: i is kkey and item is value so what you require extraa

Comment: item.0 for key item.1 for value

Comment: I have a dictionary and I want the next item each time and I want to know the key and the value of location i .

Comment: As dictionaries are unordered by definition and making an array of it is a kind of a hack you will never get the same order.

Comment: I tried item.0 for key item.1 but it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cycle like this:

```
let d = ["hey":1, "ho":2, "hey nonny no":3]
let keys = Array(d.keys)
for (ix,k) in keys.enumerated() {
    print("This is", k, "and value is", d[k]!)
    if ix < keys.count-1 {
        print("Next is", keys[ix+1], "and value is", d[keys[ix+1]]!)
    }
}
```

I'm only cycling through the keys, but once you have a key, you can trivially fetch the corresponding value from the original dictionary, as you can see.

Do keep in mind, though, that a dictionary is unordered, so the notion of a "next key" is kind of meaningless.

Comment: I know it is not ordered I just need a way to access the next item in the dictionary when a button clicked without knowing the key

Comment: Okay, but I'm warning you that there is no reliable concept of "the next item in the dictionary". If you want something where is a "next item" you should be using an array from the start, not trying to turn a dictionary _into_ an array.